# Charset comparison

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, normalization, unicode-normalization, text-normalization

I need urgent help. I can't compare charset strings. A string written to a database table1 is `utf-8 charset` but looks still strange: ＳＡＤＩ
However a string written to table2 in the same database is `SADI` which is normal.
whenever I compare both, it gives false.

1. Any idea how comparison can be made? (actually comparison should give true result)
2. Any idea how I can insert ＳＡＤＩ as `SADI` to a database.

Either will be a solution hopefully.

Comment: This is a good question but not about charsets. It is about comparing Ascii strings and strings of fullwidth characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your strings, `SADI` is standard ASCII string, but `ＳＡＤＩ` is using full-width Unicode characters.

For example, `Ｓ` is [U+FF33 'FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff33/index.htm) (UTF-8: `0xEF 0xBC 0xB3`),

but `S` is standard ASCII [U+0053 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/53/index.htm) (UTF-8 `0x53`).

Other characters are also similar extended Unicode characters, which look like standard Latin script, but in reality are not.

How did they get there - that's a good question. Probably somebody got really creative and copy-pasted something from Word? Who knows.

You can convert these strange characters back to normal ones by applying Unicode NFKC ([Unicode Normalization Form KC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization)) by using this Perl script as a filter (it accepts UTF-8 and outputs normalized UTF-8):

```
use Unicode::Normalize;
binmode STDIN,  ':utf8';
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
while(<>) { print NFKC($_); }
```

In php:

```
$result = Normalizer::normalize( $str, Normalizer::FORM_KC );
```

Requires the [intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)

Comment: A good analysis and a good solution, but depending on the data as a whole, it may be of importance that converting to NFKC discards many other distinctions too, not just the distinction between Ascii letters and their full-width counterparts. E.g., the distinction between micro sign µ and the Greek smaller letter mu μ, or the distinction between the ellipsis character “…” and three periods “...”.

Comment: Somebody in Eastern Asia typed that string.  These glyphs exists to keep the letter pitch in Western and Asian words consistent.

Comment: Still I can't handle this. intl extension seems not working despite enabling in WAMP server. I used other method:

Comment: Still I can't handle this. intl extension seems not working despite enabling in WAMP server. I used other method: $translit = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str).However I am not sure if it is safe.This normalizes but not converts from ASCII to FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL.To be specific, I need to select the row where ＳＡＤＩ== SADI in MySQL.This means SADI needs to be converted to ＳＡＤＩ. Or any other solutions? Plz help me I am fed up all day searching...Yeah actually things are a bit complicated.The string entails Korean character which looks: $str = "ＳＡＤＩ탐요"

Comment: @user1971424 just get intl working... did you reboot server after enabling the extension?

Comment: Yes I restarted the server. But the output is same. Intl extention is not working.